# Match tags inside tag

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I want to modify:

`<ins><br/> <b>bold</b> <br/><br/> <br/>  <br/></ins> <br/> <ins> <br/> </ins>`

to:

`<ins><br/>NL: <b>bold</b> <br/>NL:<br/>NL: <br/>NL:  <br/>NL:</ins> <br/> <ins> <br/>NL: </ins>`

(inside every `<ins>` and `</ins>` tag find and change `<br/>` to `<br/>NL:`. Ignore `<br/>` outside `<ins>`. Also, `<ins>` might contain various other tags)

To do this, I have this peace of code:

```
 $string= preg_replace('~(?:<ins>|(?!^)\G)(.*?)<br\/>~', '$0NL:', $string);
```

https://regex101.com/r/xI8mW9/4

It would work just fine, but the problem is that matching doesn't end after `</ins>` tag. How do I replace `<br/>` with `<br/>NL:` only withing `<ins>` and `</ins>` tags. It modifies every `<br/>` after first `<ins>`

I have also tried pattern:

`~(<ins>.*?)(?<my_br><br/>)(?!NL:)(.*?</ins>)~`

https://regex101.com/r/xI8mW9/15

(in this case for each my_br changed as $1$2NL:$3) Problem: In case `<ins><br/></ins><br/><ins><br/></ins>` middle `<br/>` is affected.

Tried doing it with `DOMDocument` as suggested in comment:

```
    $rendered_diff = "Some<ins>a<br/></ins><br/><ins>b<br/></ins>text";
    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($rendered_diff);
    $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ins');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
        foreach ($items->item($i)->childNodes as $node) {
            if ($node->nodeName == 'br') {
                $node->appendData('NL:');
            }
        }
    }
    $doc->saveHTML();
    dd($rendered_diff);
```

Got an error:

```
    ERROR: Call to undefined method DOMElement::appendData()
```

Have no idea why this approach is bad.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse or modify XML/HTML. Use `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @hek2mgl Tried, not sure what's wrong.

Comment: You say that your second regex is catches the middle one too, but I fail to see how it does that. I checked in on regex.com and it didn't do i there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
<?php
$rendered_diff = "<br/>Some<ins>a<br/><div>blablaa</div></ins><br/><ins>b<br/></ins>text";
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($rendered_diff);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ins');
foreach ($xpath->query("//ins/br") as $br) {
    $text = $doc->createTextNode('NS:');
    $br->parentNode->insertBefore( $text, $br->nextSibling);
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

It outputs the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><br/>Some<ins>a<br/>NS:<div>blablaa</div></ins><br/><ins>b<br/>NS:</ins>text</body></html>
```

Which seems to solve the problem.

Note that I modified a bit your initial XML, to test your

> Ignore `<br/>` outside `<ins>`

condition. See the 1st `<br/>`.

Answering your question

> Have no idea why this approach is bad.

Your approach is not good because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and compare it with the code I placed above: doesn't the latter look cleaner? And moreover, it uses XPath and you can create more complicated queries to match certain elements, not only `<br>`'s inside `<ins>`

Comment: Thank You. I didn't edit my question, but I found out that it also can be anchieved with regex: `<ins>(?:[^<]++|<(?!br/>(?!NL:)|/ins>))*+\K(?<my_br><br/>)(?=(?:[^<]++|<(?!/ins>))*+</ins>)` (just for the record)

Comment: do you think that maintaining this regex is an easy task? Easier than XML manipulation? Up to you of course